# Using global unicast address as source for neighbor solicitation messages

Tags: ipv6, ndp

Why do neighbor solicitation messages only use the link local address as source? What would be the advantages and disadvantages of using the global unicast address instead?

Answer (score 1):

Since neighbors are on the locally connected network, there is no reason to use global addresses, as the packets will never leave the local network.  Also neighbor solicitation will function correctly regardless of whether global addresses are configured or not.

Comment: You can also ask more detailed IPv6 questions on Network Engineering SE.